# Is it possible to open SWF file in android application?

Tags: android

I have requirement to open swf file in my android application, and i have tried a lot to find the solution for it but not getting any perfect solution.
can you please tell me is it possible to open swf file in android application and how?

Comment: Show us what you have tried yet.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use webview to load the SWF file,

use this as reference

````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````
    ```````````````````````````````````````````````````````````
    mWebView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webview);
    mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    mWebView.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);


    String html = "<object width=\"768\" height=\"1024\"> <param name=\"movie\" value=\"file:///android_asset/androidswf.swf\"> <embed src=\"file:///android_asset/androidswf.swf\" width=\"768\" height=\"1024\"> </embed> </object>";
    String mimeType = "text/html";
    String encoding = "utf-8";
    mWebView.loadDataWithBaseURL("null", html, mimeType, encoding, "");
    ```````````````````````````````
````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````

Also add `android:hardwareAccelerated="true"` for the activity in manifest file.

Comment: I have tried this and getting white screen only @deepThought.

Comment: I am using mWebView.getSettings().setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON); in place of mWebView.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true); due to plugin deprecate.

Comment: have you added this in manifest android:hardwareAccelerated="true" ?

Comment: webView = binding.wvLoad;
      webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);
        webView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
        String html = "<object width=\"768\" height=\"1024\"> <param name=\"movie\" value=\"file:///android_asset/car_file.swf\"> <embed src=\"file:///android_asset/car_file.swf\" width=\"768\" height=\"1024\"> </embed> </object>";
        String mimeType = "text/html";
        String encoding = "utf-8";
        webView.loadDataWithBaseURL("null", html, mimeType, encoding, "");

Comment: <layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <data>

        <variable
            name="vm"
            type="com.techwin.myapplication.ui.welcome.WelcomeActivityVM" />
    </data>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/icon_color">

        <WebView
            android:id="@+id/wv_load"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    </RelativeLayout>
</layout>
this is my layout file